# Error on converting dataframe to SQL - Pandas

Tags: mysql, pandas

I am getting this error: DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement. when trying to convert my dataframe to sql

**My connection variable:**

```
con = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="****",
  port="****",
  database="*****",
  user="*****",
  password="*****"
)
```

My try to convert it to sql:

```
df.to_sql('menageiro2',con)
```

Note: **I am using**:

- import pandas as pd
- import sqlalchemy
- import mysql.connector

Comment: You leaked your password so make sure you change that.  The error means that the sql query expects input for the name bind variable.   Can you post a self-contained example to demonstrate the issue?  Otherwise I cannot debug this for you. Others may be able to of course.

Comment: DUDE THANKS A LOT LMAOF. I did not notice that

Comment: You mean a picture of the dataframe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Pictures are better than nothing but that means if I try to run your code, I have to transcribe it to text.  It's better if you post an actual minimal example of a program that exhibit the issue.  That said, see my answer below (my current best guess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#r689dfd12abe5-1) says `con: sqlalchemy.engine.(Engine or Connection) or sqlite3.Connection`.  You appear to be passing in a mysql connection instead of a SQLAlchamy engine (that you connected to MySQL):

```
con = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
'mysql+mysqlconnector://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<default_db>...')
```

Comment: Do I have to take off  "< >"?

Comment: Thanks a lot man! That was the problem. Do you know why do I have to use SQLAlchemy engine?

Comment: That was the choice of whoever wrote the pandas to_sql() function.  SQLAlchamy probably works as comparability layer, so they can support more database without having to write a bunch per database specific code.